# jquery/ajax autologin to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have this code in python :

```
import requests

session=requests.Session()

def login_mps_api(username, password):
    MyHeaderss = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.32 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.32",
                  "X-GWT-Permutation" : "6FEFBE57C6E73F0AB33BD5A4E17945DE",
                  "Content-Type":"text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8",
                  "X-GWT-Module-Base": "https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/",
                  "Referer": "https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/titolari.html"}


    login_data = '''7|0|7|https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/|FEAC78FFDF81D6121438D70986AF1C41|portale.titolari.client.service.PTService|login|portale.titolari.client.common.login.LoginRequest/3583069702|{password}|{username}|1|2|3|4|1|5|5|0|0|6|7|'''.format(username=username, password=password)
    ra0=session.post('https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/service', data=login_data, headers=MyHeaderss)
```

I need to make a similar request using ajax/jquery, the problem is that I need to use specific headers like in my python code, how can i do this using jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

here's how you go about it:

```
var MyHeaderss = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.32 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.32",
              "X-GWT-Permutation" : "6FEFBE57C6E73F0AB33BD5A4E17945DE",
              "Content-Type":"text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8",
              "X-GWT-Module-Base": "https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/",
              "Referer": "https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/titolari.html"};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
      request.setRequestHeader(MyHeaderss);
    },
    url: 'https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/service',
    data: login_data,
    success: function(databak) {
    }
});
```

Comment: how i can setup my custom headers ? like my python code ?

Comment: exactly as you did in python, use the same object

Comment: no you have to define it before `$.ajax({...` and define it with a `var` let me update the answer for you

Comment: login_data similar to MyHeaders ? start define whit var ?

Comment: I think yeah, but I really don't understand the string inside `login_data`, is it supposed to be a string? or a regex maybe?